Prevent batch-file terminating early following a call to a third party CLI command
I'm trying to automate the creation of some boiler plate code using calls to a third party CLI (ArcGIS Enterprise Custom Data Feed) with a batch file. However, once the call to the first CLI command cdf createapp <app name> completes, the batch file exits, and so the rest of the script is not executed.
The call to createapp is doing what it should, but then it seemingly returns something which causes the batch file to stop at that point. Is there a way to handle this to stop this from happening?
I've tried putting the CLI commands in their own separate batch files and then calling them from the original batch file, but this didn't help.
Code snippet below:
The script just stops after the successful execution of cdf createapp, with no error message.
@echo off
echo Start of create cdpk script
echo ---------------------------
set cdf-app-name=%1
set data-provider-name=%2
echo Supplied arguments cdf-app-name=%cdf-app-name%, data-provider-name=%data-provider-name%
echo Creating new cdf app (%cdf-app-name%)...
cdf createapp %cdf-app-name%
cd %cdf-app-name%
echo Creating new cdf provider (%data-provider-name%)...
cdf createprovider %data-provider-name%
cd providers\%data-provider-name%
echo Installing packages (ws, node-fetch, uuid)...
npm install ws@8.15.1
npm install node-fetch@2.7.0
npm install uuid@9.0.1
cd ..\..\..\
echo Copying source files (constructGeoJSON.js, model.js)...
 


Try "CALL cdf..."

Thanks for all the valuable feedback. Actually the first comment by magoo did the trick, namely adding CALL before the cdf calls. But the rest was very handy to learn. echooff was something that had happened with the copy paste, it was echo off in the script Mofi. Also, I'd created a little confusion by saying I'd tried splitting out calls in separate batch files. The code was the original single batch file solution.
@echo off
echo Start of create cdpk script
echo ---------------------------
set cdf-app-name=%~1
set data-provider-name=%~2
echo Supplied arguments cdf-app-name=%cdf-app-name%, data-provider-name=%data-provider-name%
echo Creating new cdf app (%cdf-app-name%)...
call cdf.cmd createapp %cdf-app-name%
cd %cdf-app-name%
echo Creating new cdf provider (%data-provider-name%)...
call cdf.cmd createprovider %data-provider-name%
cd providers\%data-provider-name%
echo Installing packages (ws, node-fetch, uuid)...
call npm.cmd install ws@8.15.1
call npm.cmd install node-fetch@2.7.0
call npm.cmd install uuid@9.0.1
cd ..\..\..\
echo Copying source files (constructGeoJSON.js, model.js)...


If a file has an extension, please use it. There is no good reason to omit them in a script; that type of 'lazy' use is for speedy interactive commandline entry. You only type it into the script once! It also makes your code more understandable as a future reader would find it simpler to understand the use of Call, if it is only used when the extension of the file it is running is .cmd or .bat. It would also be preferable if you change set cdf-app-name=%1, and set data-provider-name=%2, to set "cdf-app-name=%~1" and set "data-provider-name=%~2" respectively.

Thanks Compo, I'll bare that in mind about using extensions.
What was the purpose of the tilde when setting the named parameters?

If, as you should always, you pass a doublequoted argument string to your batch file, the tilde removes those surrounding doublequotes. Within your script, if the expanded variable content requires doublequoting, it is done in use, i.e. "%cdf-app-name%", and "%data-provider-name%".

@DrDarrio The batch file as is does not work for any possible directory/app name. Run your batch file with first argument being "Development & Test 100% (!)" from within a command prompt window and see what happens now. Insert as second line setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion and append at the bottom endlocal. Modify set cdf-app-name=%~1 to set "cdf-app-name=%~1" and set data-provider-name=%2 to set "data-provider-name=%~2". Insert next setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion as needed for the next two echo command lines.

@DrDarrio echo Supplied arguments cdf-app-name=!cdf-app-name!, data-provider-name=!data-provider-name! and echo Creating new cdf app (!cdf-app-name!)... work now with the usage of delayed variable expansion even on uncommon cdf app name containing an ampersand or other characters with special meaning for cmd.exe. The next line should be endlocal to restore the previous environment with disabled delayed variable expansion. Modify call cdf.cmd createapp %cdf-app-name% to call cdf.cmd createapp "%cdf-app-name%" and cd %cdf-app-name% to cd "%cdf-app-name%".

@DrDarrio echo Creating new cdf provider (%data-provider-name%)... needs to be changed to setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo Creating new cdf provider (!data-provider-name!)...& endlocal for an always working output of this message. Then change the next two lines to: call cdf.cmd createprovider "%data-provider-name%" and cd "providers\%data-provider-name%" The batch file works now even for argument strings passed to the batch file containing &%()! and every other character possible in a file/folder name.
